# Create NSString from certain point on of other NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, ipad

I have a NSString with the following text:

```
You can now download "file.png" from "http://www.example.com/RANDOM.png"
```

How can I create a new NSString with the URL from that string? I would want:

```
http://www.example.com/RANDOM.png
```

I would normally just remove the beginning text, but "file.png" could be any file name of any length and cannot be removed with `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` (since I don't know what it is). Any ideas of how to remove everything up to the end of `from "`? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSRange range = [string rangeOfString:@"from \""];
NSString *URL = [string substringFromIndex:range.location + range.length];
```

Error checking might be a good idea (ie `range.location != NSNotFound`). You'd also have to strip the last `"` from the string, but there is a `substringToIndex:` method which, combined with the strings length, can do this (I leave this up to you, its trivial).

Comment: The location returned by `rangeOfString` is the beginning of that string.  So you'd have to do: `[string substringFromIndex:(range.location + range.length)]`;

Comment: @DanF Whoops, you are of course right! Will edit, thanks for catching this.

Comment: I believe that that will fail if the filename is something like "from meh.png". A regular expression would probably be better in this case. Or start from the second to last '"' all the to the end.

Comment: @nms No, your example filename won't fail... It would fail if the file name ends with `from` and a space.

Comment: Ah, true that, I missed that '\""'. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use regular expression that will recognize the url. Here is an example which uses the URL match RegEx from @gruber, you might have to tweak it a bit depending on the actual output of the server:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\b(([\\w-]+://?|www[.])[^\\s()<>]+(?:\\([\\w\\d]+\\)|([^[:punct:]\\s]|/)))" options:NSRegularExpressionAnchorsMatchLines | NSRegularExpressionAllowCommentsAndWhitespace error:NULL];
NSRange range = [regex rangeOfFirstMatchInString:myString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [myString length])];
NSString *URL = [myString substringWithRange:range];
```

Comment: +1 because regular expressions aren't used enough in ObjC applications, -1 for providing only one half of the answer...

Comment: Totally Agree. I am writing from my iPhone and couldn't provide code for substrings :). Point taken :)

Comment: Took the freedom to add an example and give you the +1

Comment: Code seems legit :) Btw as you say regex-es aren't used enough in Objective-c I would say i'd prefer to skip them because of the overhead, but in cases you aren't sure about the string, it's the right decision... I mean, in this case if the result is hardcoded (by you), probably the regex is not the best suggestion, but overall i'd use them instead looking for substrings...

Comment: -1 because you shouldn't be using a regex for this. You should be using an `NSDataDetector` to detect URLs in the source string.